# Using 2 different code blocks on the same line

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my code:

````
message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setDescription("```fix\nMember " + "``` = " + "```bash\n" + member.id + "\n```")
 .setColor("#black"));
````

I'm trying to use 2 different code blocks on the same line.

In the same row I want member yellow, = colorless, member.id blue. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single backtick ` for one line code blocks.
For example `test` `test` will appear to be on the same line. I don't believe it is possible to add syntax highlighting to these one line codeblocks. Take a look at [this article](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617) for other types of discord markdown.

Comment: Logger bot can do this [link](https://i.hizliresim.com/y1UqKR.png)

Comment: From what I can see that is a multi line code block using "ml" syntax highlighting I figured out how to reproduce it by typing
\```ml  
Test = 1234  
Test2 =1234  
\```
(I'm unsure how to add linebreaks in stack overflow comments but these need to each be on their own line and it should work)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can't be done but it can be done this way

````
message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setDescription("```css\n{Member: " + `'${member}'` + "}\n{Member_id: " + `'${member.id}'` +"}```")
 .setColor("#black"));
````